# How does Volley singleton make parallel requests when the thread pool shares one instance of the HTTP Client?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-volley, android-networking

When a single Volley RequestQueue is created, it initializes a BasicNetwork object using a http client. It also creates a default thread pool of 4 for taking requests from the queue and executing them.

Now there is only 1 BasicNetwork object with the queue and the BasicNetwork.this.performRequest(...) method is a blocking call. So how does Volley parallelize the requests?

Comment: I don't know volley, but you could be looking at HTTP pipelining ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining)).

Comment: A blocking call only means that it's synchronous (i.e. uses the current thread) - the other threads should not be blocked.